# Named properties for CALENDER items

Tags: calendar, mime, mapi

I want to know whether I have to fetch PropertyID for PidLidAppointmentDuration using GetNamesFromIDs(), like the way we do for Named-Property.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433490%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx
2.11   PidLidAppointmentDuration 
Canonical name: PidLidAppointmentDuration 
Description: Specifies the length of the event, in minutes. 
Property set: PSETID_Appointment {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
Property long ID (LID): 0x00008213 
Data type: PtypInteger32, 0x0003
```

Here microsoft gives PropertyID right way. So can I use 0x8213 directly without calling GetNamesFromIDs(). More importantly, will 0x8213 work in every environment.

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 2):

This is not at all what it means: property id here is what you pass (along with the GUID) when calling GetIdsFromNames.